# Unable to convert response from Graph to a GraphEdge because the response does not look like a GraphEdge

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using this code snippet:

```
// posting on user timeline using publish_actins permission
try {
        // message must come from the user-end
        $data = ['message' => 'something...'];
        $request = $fb->post('/me/feed', $data);
        $response = $request->getGraphEdge()->asArray;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
```

And I get this alert but I successfully post in my wall:

> "Facebook SDK returned an error: Unable to convert response from Graph
>   to a GraphEdge because the response does not look like a GraphEdge.
>   Try using GraphNodeFactory::makeGraphNode() instead."

Can someone help me please?

Comment: `Facebook->post` method returns a [`FacebookResponse`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookResponse/5.0.0) object.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check if you've asked for relevant permissions ([check here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)) 
then try to check the **$request** and see what you have inside it.
It normally happens in 2 cases:
1. when your request has no response (for example in this case you've got nothing on your feed)
2. when the response itself is a GraphEdge

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

$request->getGraphEdge();

Answer (score 0):

You have to change **$response** to this code

```
$response = $request->getGraphNode();
$id = $response['id'];
```